# Hist table for character string in R

Tags: r, character, histogram

I have a list of data (csv file). I've imported the data into my RStudio. When I try to make a histogram table in order to observe the frequency of each category I get this error:

> `'x' must be numeric`

```r
hist(tested_individuals$`Corona_result`, 
  breaks = 3, 
  main = "Corona test indication", 
  ylim = c(0,1100), 
  labels = c("0","1","2"))
```

Comment: Hitograms are for numeric values. If you have categorical values and want counts, use a bar plot. Try `barplot(table(tested_individuals$\`Corona_result\`))`

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.